# While running cypress test from gitbash CLI unable to set the ENV

Tags: node.js, cypress, git-bash

I am trying to run bellow cypress run command from git bash, all my idea is to set `--env ENV="production"` and if its production it should pick up  the production url and run the test. This is not working for me ,when I `printenv` from CLI it is not showing the `ENV` value set. Could someone please advise ?

```
Cypress version : 10.11.0 

Git bash version: 2.38.1 windows 11 Pro

Node : v18.12.0
```

note: I was referring to this link >> https://dzone.com/articles/configure-cypress-tests-to-run-on-multiple-environments

From git CLI, run command:

```
npx cypress run --env ENV="production" --env grepTags="@Envtest"
```

Calling the below function:

```
function chooseTestEnv() {
    const envi = Cypress.env('ENV');
    console.log("Where is my env pointing at::"+envType);
    switch(envi){
        case "production":
           console.log("Run against Production url")
           cy.visit("https://www.producttiontest.com/");
           break;

        case "staging":
            
           console.log("Run against Staging Prexit url");
           cy.visit("https://staging-test.com/");
           break;

        default:
            
            console.log("All good, by default it always run against Staging");
            let urlDefault = Cypress.config().baseUrl;
            cy.visit(urlDefault);
            
    }
    
}
```

inside the test:

```
beforeEach(() => {
        helpFunction.chooseTestEnv();
        cy.reload();
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know much about git-bash, but if I run your command line using `cypress open`

```js
npx cypress open --env ENV="production" --env grepTags="@Envtest"
```

then take a look at Setting on the left of the Cypress runner, under section **Resolved configuration** I can see

```js
env: {
  grepTags: '@Envtest',
},
```

So it looks like the problem is the 2nd `--env` replaces the first one.

---

**Multiple --env vars is broken**

But if I try the documented way of passing multiple `--env` see [cypress command line](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/command-line#cypress-open-env-lt-env-gt), the 2nd example in this section which has multiple vars separated by a comma:

```js
cypress open --env host=api.dev.local,port=4222
```

I get

```js
env: {
  host: 'api.dev.local port=4222',
},
```

instead of expected

```js
env: {
  host: 'api.dev.local`,
  port: 'x4222',
},
```

---

**A workaround**

With this command line:

```js
npx cypress open --env ENV="production",grepTags="@Envtest"
```

You can patch the problem in a `before()`

```js
before(() => {
  const ENV = Cypress.env('ENV')
  Cypress.env('ENV', ENV.split(' ')[0])
  const grep = ENV.split(' ')[1]
  Cypress.env(grep.split('=')[0], grep.split('=')[1])
})

it('check env vars passed on command line', () => {
  expect(Cypress.env('ENV')).to.eq('production')
  expect(Cypress.env('grepTags')).to.eq('@Envtest')
})
```

It fixes your `production` flag, but there's still an issue with `cypress-grep` because it processes tags before the test code starts.

Comment: I have accepted and upvoted the answer.

Comment: Was trying to find a way to set `grepTags` before startup - like [Option #3: CYPRESS_*](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/environment-variables#Option-3-CYPRESS_) , `cypress_grepTags=@Envtest`

Comment: Ok, I will share my result, could you please let me if that is a good approach!